# how to set a limit on a sum function in gbq?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wondering if there's a way to cap a total of a summation in GBQ? For example, I'd like the function to randomly sum all records until it hit a total of 3,000,000.

Thank you!

Comment: simple `select 3000000`? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a column with the sum of all preceding rows. Set the `where` on this column.

```
Select * from (
Select x,value,
 sum(value) over (rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as agg_sum
from
(Select  rand() as x, value from unnest(generate_array(1,10000) ) as value
order by x)
)
where agg_sum <30000
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.